# Streetview Api, lock pitch (vertical panning)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-street-view

I'm working with Google Streetview Api and I'm trying to lock the pitch so the user can only pan left or right. This is what I tried

```
panorama.addListener('pov_changed', function(e) {
    var curHeading = panorama.getPov().heading;
    this.setPov({
        'pitch': 0,
        'heading': curHeading
    });
});
```

Unfortunately, what happens is the "setPov" method triggers another 'pov_changed' so this ends up in an infinite loop. What should I do to keep my pitch at 0?

Answer (score 2):

you can avoid using setter `(setPov)` and directly override the pitch value.

Modify your eventHandler to (this won't trigger the infinite loop.):

```js
panorama.addListener('pov_changed', function(e) {
  if (!this.pov.pitch) { return; }
  this.pov.pitch = 0;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From this [`StreetViewPov object specification`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#StreetViewPov),

> **`pitch`**
>
> - The camera pitch in degrees, relative to the street view vehicle. Ranges from 90° (directly upwards) to -90° (directly downwards).

Try to keep to 0 to make the POV camera move left to right.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yup, the question I was asking was how to keep it at zero. If you check the code above I'm trying to get it to set pov to 0 when ever the pov changes. The trouble is this triggers another pov_changed event which puts this into an infinite loop.